# users getting my previous bundle

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with my production website.

when users enter my website after building they getting a white screen.
I saw on the dev tools that the website trying to load the old bundle.js file and I don't understand why (the cashing is off)

Comment: are you using Webpack ? and webpackHTML plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a problem of a running service worker.

service worker is an API that cache your assets and other files so when a user is offline or having a slow network, he can still see your website.

React creates a service worker for you without your configuration by default, so this is the reason users enter your website and getting your previous bundle.

just put this in your app so next time user will enter your website, the service worker will be terminated.

```
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';

// ....

unregister();
```

- [Service Workers, MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)
- [Service Workers, Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/)

Comment: Does this not defeat the purpose of having the service worker in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using webpack to generate the builds and want [caching (with service workers)](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker) to work as well, you can:

1. Add hashes to your generated bundles. Then, your webpack config may look like this:

   ```
   {
       output: {
           path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
           filename: "[name].[chunkhash].js",
       },
   }
   ```

   [Read more about it here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/).
2. Do not cache your `index.html` which contains `<script>` imports of the updated hash-named bundles.

This will enable you to cache your builds easily, and only fetch new bundles whenever there is an update in the hash-names.